# Prove a limit exists, and find the answer

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose $x_1 = 1$ and that $2x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{3}{x_n}$ for $n \geq 1$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists, and find the limit.

Would anyone mind giving me help here, the way we prove these exist confuses me.  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Compute $x_2,x_3,x_4$ and make a hypothesis on how the sequence behaves so that you could show it converges.

Comment: Hint: study the monotony of f(x) = (x+3/x)/2, and find its fixed points

Comment: This sequence is Newton's method for approximating $\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the sequence has a limit and then it is simple to determine what that limiting value would be (taking the limit of and applying typical limit theorems to the definition of the sequence). Then you just need to show that the sequence is always moving closer to that limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show that:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{3}$

[If you follow the definition then the next step:

Prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists N such that if $n \geq N$, then $|x_n - \sqrt{3}| < \epsilon$

Assuming that $\epsilon$ is given, can you find $N$?]

A better approach is to show that the sequence converges monotonically and is bounded and hence has a limit. Then show that the limit is $\sqrt{3}$

1. Let $x_n > \sqrt{3}$, then it follows $\sqrt{3} < x_{n+1} < x_n$

(i) $x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{x_n} - x_n) = \frac{3-x_n^2}{2x_n} < 0$

(ii) $x_{n+1}^2 - 3 = \frac{1}{4}(x_n^2 + 6 + \frac{9}{x_n^2}) - 3 = \frac{1}{4}(x_n^2 - 6 + \frac{9}{x_n^2}) = \frac{1}{4}(x_n - \frac{3}{x_n})^2 = \frac{(x_n^2-3)^2}{4x_n^2} > 0$

2. A monotonic decreasing sequence bounded below is convergent. If $x_1 < \sqrt{3}$, we have already shown above that $x_2 > \sqrt{3}$. For $n > 2$, the sequence is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt{3}$
3. The limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ satisfies $x = \frac{1}{2}(x + \frac{3}{x})$. We can solve it to see $x = \sqrt{3}$

Comment: Ah yes I figured that out since if $x_n$ has a limit $x_{n+1}$ has the same limit.  But does this prove it exists and solve it at the same time?